# Browser not displaying basic http server response

Tags: java, http, http-headers, httpresponse

Have a task to create a basic http server. I've gotten to the point where it asks you to send text response back that should be displayed in your browser if you go to http://localhost:8080/ but I just get a page cannot be displayed error. I think it must be something to do with the format of the response I'm sending but i just can't get it. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class HttpServer{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8080);
            while(true){
                HttpServerSession sesh = new HttpServerSession(ss.accept());
                sesh.start();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("IOException");
        }
    }
}

class HttpServerSession extends Thread {
    private Socket client;
    public HttpServerSession(Socket client){
        this.client = client;
    }

private void println(BufferedOutputStream bos, String s) throws IOException {
    String news = s + "\r\n";
    byte[] array = news.getBytes();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        bos.write(array[i]);
    }
    return;
}

public void run(){
    try{
        InetAddress clientIP = client.getInetAddress();
        System.out.println("We just got a message! " + clientIP.getHostAddress());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        String request = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(request);
        String[] parts = request.split(" ");
        if(parts.length == 3){
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            String filename = parts[1].substring(1);
            if(parts[0].equals("GET")){
                while(true){
                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    System.out.println(line);
                    if(line == null || line.equals("")){
                        break;
                    }
                }
                println(bos, "OK");
                println(bos, "");
                println(bos, "Hello World");
            }
        }
        client.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Exception in thread");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What does the header look like that you are sending out?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
replaced the OK in the first call to println with it but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just had to flush the `BufferedOutputStream`